# assigning multiple variables with or without round braces?

Tags: python

Is there any difference (and what) between these assignments?:

```
t=("a",5,2.1)
a,b,c = t
```

and

```
t=("a",5,2.1)
(a,b,c) = t
```

?

I found both versions in multiple web sources and don't know what are these braces for in second version.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences explains why.

Comment: And for the nitty gritty there is always the [reference documentation for assignment statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). The `target_list` is a comma-separated sequence of names, and you can put these names in parenthesis and in brackets. And you can even nest these. `(a, b), c = (1, 2), 3` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

You can use [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#module-dis) module to verify.

```
>>> t=("a", 5, 2.1)
>>> def first():
    a, b, c = t

>>> def second():
    (a, b, c) = t

>>> dis.dis(first)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (t)
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(second)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (t)
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only difference is for readability.

Comment: @Tim It's misleading to single out return statements. They parentheses are optional everywhere where precedence isn't in the way. That includes other contexts than return statements, such as `t = a, b` (as in the question). The parentheses aren't even part of tuple syntax proper; the **comma** makes the tuple. It's just that the comma has rather low precedence. Note that lines like `a, = [1]` and `t = 1,` do work.

Comment: And most importantly, you could refer to the [documentation for assignments](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) to show that both spellings have the same outcome.

Comment: They are also optional with a return statement. They are required when you need to specify a tuple within another syntax structure say call to a function my_function(("a", 5), 2.1)

Comment: @Tim What you are saying about passing parameters to a function is correct. However - that is not part of the question, and no one is questioning that. This question is about assignment through unpacking a variable. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @InbarRose the op is asking if parentheses are required, I am presenting an example of when they are, Martijns comment attached to the question gives a better example of when they are required.